# PostgreSQL Trigger Error : control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger on a column of my table like this in Postgresql 9.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.combo_min_stock()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$combo_sync$

DECLARE combo_product_ids INTEGER[] := array(SELECT combo_product_map.combo_productid FROM app.combo_product_map WHERE combo_product_map.productid=NEW.productid);
DECLARE comboid INTEGER;

BEGIN

  -- UPDATE MINIMUM STOCK FOR COMBO SKUS --

   FOREACH comboid IN ARRAY combo_product_ids
   LOOP

      UPDATE app.inventory SET
        good_stock = combo_data.min_good_stock,
        bad_stock = combo_data.min_bad_stock,
        to_be_updated = true
      FROM
        (SELECT
          product.productid,
          MIN(inventory.good_stock) as min_good_stock,
          MIN(inventory.bad_stock) as min_bad_stock
        FROM
          app.product,
          app.inventory,
          app.combo_product_map
        WHERE
          product.is_combo=true AND
          product.productid=comboid AND
          product.productid=combo_product_map.combo_productid AND
          combo_product_map.productid=inventory.productid
        GROUP BY
          product.productid) AS combo_data
      WHERE
        combo_data.productid=inventory.productid;


   END LOOP;

END; 
$combo_sync$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION app.combo_min_stock()
  OWNER TO postgres;



CREATE TRIGGER combo_sync
  AFTER UPDATE OF good_stock
  ON app.inventory
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE app.combo_min_stock();
```

When I try to edit a value for good_stock column in my inventory table, it is throwing me this error:

> An error has occurred:
>   ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function app.combo_min_stock()

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: "A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value..." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html , "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try using this:

```
   END LOOP;
   RETURN NULL;
```

Comment: try giving an elaborate answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) docs

> `function_name`
>
> A user-supplied function that is declared as taking no arguments and
> returning type `trigger`, which is executed when the trigger fires.
>
> In the syntax of `CREATE TRIGGER`, the keywords `FUNCTION` and
> `PROCEDURE` are equivalent, but the referenced function must in any
> case be a function, not a procedure. The use of the keyword
> `PROCEDURE` here is historical and deprecated.

**What is trigger function?**

Function which returns a trigger. ex:

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS trigger
```

Important bit is **trigger `function` should be `function` not a `procedure`**

Difference between Procedures and Functions according to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.htm)

> A procedure is a database object similar to a function. The key
> differences are:
>
> - Procedures are defined with the CREATE PROCEDURE command, not CREATE
>   FUNCTION.
> - **Procedures do not return a function value**; hence CREATE PROCEDURE
>   lacks a RETURNS clause. However, procedures can instead return data to
>   their callers via output parameters.
> - While a function is called as part of a query or DML command, a
>   procedure is called in isolation using the CALL command.
> - A procedure can commit or roll back transactions during its execution
>   (then automatically beginning a new transaction), so long as the
>   invoking CALL command is not part of an explicit transaction block. A
>   function cannot do that.
> - Certain function attributes, such as strictness, don't apply to
>   procedures. Those attributes control how the function is used in a
>   query, which isn't relevant to procedures.

Simply put `functions` should have a `return` statement

So each and every trigger `function` need to have a `return` statement. Some possible `return` statements for trigger functions.

```
RETURN NULL;

RETURN OLD;

RETURN NEW;
```